# Why does mathcal f give a curly brace?

Tags: math-mode, mathcal

I would like to get a curly f lowercase letter for a mathematic formula. But the following example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
$$\mathcal{f}$$
\end{document}
```

Leads to this output

[image]

I use texlive2021. I tried on overleaf and it outputs the same result. But on katex.org on the contrary the `mathcal` commands seems to be ignore.

Comment: As Sandy G points to there are no lower case cal letters, so the output is not well defined.

Comment: Regardless of your problem, you should not use `$$...$$` for displayed math in LaTeX. Always use `\[...\]` or `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}` or one of the [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) environments.